# Multiple start and end date validation in datepicker jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

I could find many codes to validate the start date and end date(End date should not be less than start date) which is working fine. consider that my page has three start and end dates to be validated in that case how am i going to do the validations with minimal lines of code.Am just a beginner would be great if someone could help me out. Also if the user manually tries to delete the date it should re enable the dates. Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/7pxaqaju/2/

```
DateCheck($("#txtFromDate"),$("#txtToDate"));  
if($("#txtFromDate").change() || $("#txtToDate").change())
    stateChange($("#txtFromDate"),$("#txtToDate"));

DateCheck($("#txtFromDate1"),$("#txtToDate1"));
 if($("#txtFromDate1").change() || $("#txtToDate1").change())
    stateChange($("#txtFromDate1"),$("#txtToDate1"));  

DateCheck($("#txtFromDate2"),$("#txtToDate2"));
 if($("#txtFromDate2").change() || $("#txtToDate2").change())
    stateChange($("#txtFromDate2"),$("#txtToDate2"));  


function DateCheck(fromDate,toDate){
     fromDate.datepicker({
         showOn: "button",
         buttonImage: "Z.jpeg",
         buttonImageOnly: true,
         numberOfMonths: 1,        
         onSelect: function(selected) {
              toDate.datepicker("option",{minDate: selected });
         }        
     });   
     toDate.datepicker({ 
         showOn: "button",
         buttonImage: "Z.jpeg",
         buttonImageOnly: true,
         numberOfMonths: 1,                    
         onSelect: function(selected) {
             fromDate.datepicker("option",{maxDate: selected});
         }
     }); 
}

 function stateChange(fromDate,toDate){   
    fromDate.change(function(){
        if(fromDate.val() == "")
        toDate.datepicker("option",{minDate : null});       
    });
    toDate.change(function(){
        if(toDate.val() == "")            
        fromDate.datepicker("option",{maxDate : null});
    }); 
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:-

add class to each from input element like this:-

```
From: <input type="text" id="txtFromDate1" class="datetimepicker from"  />
```

and now change your jQuery code :-

```
$( ".datetimepicker" ).datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "/Z.jpeg",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
   onSelect: function(date) {           
       if($(this).hasClass('from')){
         $(this).next().next().datepicker("option",{minDate: date });
       }
    },
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7pxaqaju/4/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. i need two validations 1. End date should be validated with its corresponding start date and the dates should be disabled accordingly 2. Re enable the dates if user manually deletes the date in text box. I've written the code here but its bit clumsy. I need help to optimize my code. http://jsfiddle.net/7pxaqaju/2/

Comment: yes tats right first validation is working fine. but what if all the start dates are grouped together and so the end dates. Leave out the alignment issues but this is how it kind of grouped in the original code that am working on so just asked out of curiosity. more like this http://jsfiddle.net/coolram27123/7pxaqaju/7/

Comment: Thanks both are working just fine :) just saw the other comment my bad. Just about the positioning tat  i was talking about. would be helpful if i can get a clarity on that.

Comment: hi @Ramki if both work fine can you please mark as answer. :)